# Dynamically change the contents of a blockquote

Tags: php, html, ajax, bxslider

I need to dynamically change the contents of a blockquote in my website. 
I actually have to retrieve the contents that I need to show from a database so I need to use a php script to get them and form them in the way I need.

I tried to use something like that :
http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/02/18/dynamically-loading-content-using-ajax-and-xmlhttprequest/

but without success :/

I should say that my blockquote has html in it although i don't think it matters.

Could anybody give me some help?

EDIT: Here is some code

```
<blockquote class="pro-in" id="content" style="left:-10000px; opacity:0;"></blockquote>
```

when I click on a image the blockquote get moved at the visible "plane". The contents are generated with the init(); function. The init function and the logic is described at the link provided above.

// Corrected function after suggestion from an answer below - using JQuery
    function openpro(contentNumber){

```
    $.get('phpscripts/projectsLogic.php?project='+contentNumber, function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });

    $('#content').animate({left:0, opacity:1},{duration:1600});
    $('#con').animate({left:-10000, opacity:0},{duration:1600});
}
```

If you have a better suggestion on actually creating the content rather than fixing this solution I'm up for it.
------------------------------------- bxslider
EDIT2 :

What I actually call is a bxslider (plus others). The problem is that I used to initialize the bxsliders at the $(document).ready call like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        auto: true,
        speed: 2000,
        autoHover: true,
        pause: 6000
    });
    $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
        pager: true
    });
    $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
        pager: true
    });
    ....
    });
```

When I dynamically change the contents of the div, i suppose there are no bxlider object handling the new content, so there is no visible slider. I tried putting the calls inside the function that creates the content ( openpro() ) but in vain. I also tried something like this :

```
var slide   = document.createElement("script");
        slide.type  = "text/javascript";
        slide.text  = "$(document).ready(function(){ $('#slider1').bxSlider({pager:true}); });";

        document.head.appendChild(slide);
```

but still nothing successful. Does anyone have any ideas? Sorry I'm just starting using web developing languages so I'm a bit clueless..

Comment: Please shoe YOUR code, not some external example. We can't help with things we cannot see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example with jQuery get

testFunction('lorem.txt', 'content'); //first parameter is file url and second is blockquote id

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function testFunction(path, container){
    $.get(path, function(data) {
        $('#'+container).html(data);
    });
    $('#'+container).animate({left:0, opacity:1},{duration:2000});
    $('#'+container).animate({left:-10000, opacity:0},{duration:2000});
}

</script>
<body onload="testFunction('lorem.txt', 'content');">
    <blockquote class="pro-in" id="content" style="left:-10000px; opacity:0;"></blockquote>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked thank you! The problem is that at what I call, there is actually a bxslider. In order to use it I have to do a call like this :
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bxslider'+contentNumber).bxSlider({
      pager: true;
   });

Which means that the sliders that I call do not have this object ready for them. I tried to do this call in the function that calls the content change (in your example the testFunction) but it won't work :/